# Should the ID Token or Access Token be used to authorize SPA functionality?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, openid-connect, okta

### Context

I have a Single Page Application which communicates with a backend REST API.  This REST API is made specifically to serve the SPA.  In order to navigate or use any functionality of the SPA beyond the home page, users must log in first.  I am using OIDC with Okta to authenticate users.  Users can either have an Admin role, or a User role.  Their role will be used to authorize which SPA pages they are allowed to navigate to, and which REST API calls they are allowed to make.

### Questions

1. After a user logs in, my application receives an ID token and and Access token from Okta.  I have the option for including the user's role as a custom claim in either the ID token, or the Access token.  Which token should include this information in?  Both?
2. The UI needs to make some authorization decisions based on the user role.
   For example, which HTML elements to show or hide, and which SPA routes are navigatable.  Should these decisions be made by inspecting the ID token, or the Access token?  Other?
3. When calling my backend API via the SPA should I forward the ID token and Access token that my SPA received?  Just the Access token?  Or should I set up a different authorization server for my backend REST API, and have my SPA reach out for *another* access token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some answers:

1. The id token is just an assertion to the SPA that the user is authenticated. If you are going to put the role in a token, use the access token, whose purpose is authorization
2. The API should be controlling authorization. Your SPA should ask your API, about authorized areas and the API can answer based on the access token contents. Your SPA should not read the access token directly.
3. Only send the access token to the API, which is the standard recommended behaviour

**RESPONSIBILITIES**

Generally:

- UIs can make UI decisions on which elements to show
- Of course the data they use for this needs to come from a trusted source
- UIs can read a role from id tokens and use that to control what to show
- But the API also needs the role information, to authorize requests

If you want to use role information in both UI and API, then a default option is to add the role to both the id token and the access token.

However, this does not scale well, since in a real business app you are likely to add multiple similar rules over time, and keep needing to add claims to tokens.

**EXTENSIBILITY**

A better option that is easier to manage over time, is for the UI to ask its API for the role + other data - since the API needs the same role information anyway.

Also, tokens do not need to be the only source of data for authorization decisions made by UIs and APIs. My [blog post on claims](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/) describes a pattern you can use to manage claims over time from multiple data sources.

Comment: Regarding answer #2.  Are you suggesting that, instead of the UI making UI decisions (what to show or hide for example) based on the content of a token, it should instead make a call to the API to find out what role is in the Access token?

Comment: I updated my original answer. If you want the UI to read the role from a token you would add it to the id token. However, the API will also need the role, in which case you may need to add it to the access token also.

Comment: Thanks Gary.  Your answers are clear, and thanks for hinting at an alternative I never thought about.  I'm currently reading through your blog now, and it's very informative.